# showing -0.45 in html using xsl

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am trying to format the output of xml and xsl value with one zero added only if the value is less than one and more than -1.

I want to show **-0.45** for -ve values, and for +ve values **0.45**, only if the value is in between -1 and +1. if not in that range then html itself showing properly. like 1.45 or -1.45

But what ever I use in xsl and xml or any combination, i could see output in final html page as **-.45** for -ve and **.45** for +ve.

I tried the below method also. no use...

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(-0.45, '#.00')"/>
```

This looks simple, but could not get proper solution. I am not good in xml as of now. Please share if any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as if you want `format-number(-0.45, '0.00')`.

Comment: It might be advisable to specify the second argument as '###############0.00', since the XSLT 1.0 specification is not very clear about how 12.34 should be formatted with a picture of '0.00', and there's a possibility some processors could truncate the value to make it fit in the field.